# Is firebase Unity SDK open-source project?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm newbie to use firebase Unity SDK, and downloaded the zipped file according to the instruction of "manual installation" section at https://firebase.google.com/download/unity.

The LICENSE file in the zip says "Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0", i.e. the firebase unity SDK is an open-source project.

However, I failed to find any source code of them at all, and https://firebase.google.com/docs/libraries says that the source code is not actually open-sourced.

Is the firebase Unity SDK open-source project, and is the license the Apache License v2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Unity SDK is not currently open source - [although a number of sample/test apps are](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity).

It is based on the [Firebase open source C++ SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk) (the equivalent Quickstart repo for C++ is [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp)). You can find the current state of Open Source in Firebase [here](https://firebaseopensource.com/).

The C++ SDK is released under the Apache license, and there is still source code included with the Unity SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply! It was very helpful for me!

Comment: I installed the Firebase SDK from the package manger in Unity and there is no source code included. Only dlls.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Unity SDK source code is now public.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk

The code is released under the Apache-2.0 License.